# Google Maps KML Layer won't read kml

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm trying to read a simple KML with Google Maps API 3, I created KML file in Google Maps Editor, codes are google sample, i can't find where is problem.

[gm-sample.html](https://github.com/GH-AliKazemi/GHTEST/blob/master/gm_sample.html)

[BTM.kml](https://github.com/GH-AliKazemi/GHTEST/blob/master/BTM.kml)

```
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: {lat: 40.40926, lng: 49.86709}
        });

        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: 'itdc.byethost7.com/BTM.kml',
          map: map
        });
      }
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? The KML url doesn't look good.

Comment: if you mean is browser console i can't see anything.

Comment: Does the kml file get requested from the server? Check the Network tab in Chrome DevTools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link provided for the KML on github.com is being served with a MIME type of "text/plain", it should be ["application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml"](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut)

> **3 KML MIME Types**
> When responding to a request from Google Earth (or any Earth browser), a KML server must follow a certain set of rules so that Google Earth can correctly interpret its responses.
>
> Upon success, the server must return a response code of HTTP 200 and set the response's content-type to a suitable MIME type, as described here.
>
> Google Earth reads KML and KMZ files. The MIME type for KML files is
> application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml
>
> The MIME type for KMZ files is
> application/vnd.google-earth.kmz

[validator results](http://www.feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FGH-AliKazemi%2FGHTEST%2Fmaster%2FBTM.kml):

> **Recommendations**
>
> This feed is valid, but interoperability with the widest range of feed readers could be improved by implementing the following recommendations.
>
> Feeds should not be served with the "text/plain" media type

If I copy your KML to my server (which serves KML with the correct MIME type), [it works](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/BTM.kml)

[BTW - If I point the validator to the link in the code in your question, it doesn't work at all, it isn't a KML file](http://www.feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fitdc.byethost7.com%2FBTM.kml), but if I point the KmlLayer URL to that, [it also works](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://itdc.byethost7.com/BTM.kml)